# CSV Helpers quoting everything

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am wanting to quote just strings in [csvhelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) however this is quoting every field including the header record. I obv do not want the header record to be included in the quoting is their a way to skip it and also only quote strings.

```
 public static void writeCsvFile(List<SOPOrder> sopOrders, string filename)
 {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.Configuration.TrimOptions=CsvHelper.Configuration.TrimOptions.Trim;

            csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
            csv.WriteRecords(sopOrders);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Your definition of `ShouldQuote` says quote every field. Is there a reason the default doesn't work for you? The context passed in has a property `HasHeaderBeenWritten` you can use to determine if you are in the header...

Comment: What is `field`? It look slike maybe you're setting `ShouldQuote` to `True` always. See https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1221 for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good way in CsvHelper to only quote string fields.  You can hack it though by not quoting any fields and then using a custom `StringConverter` to do the quoting of the string fields.

```cs
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "First, Record" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "Second \"Record" },
        new Foo { Id = 3, Name = "" },
        new Foo { Id = 4 }
    };

    csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => false;
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new QuoteStringConverter());

    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "\"\"";

        return "\"" + ((string)value).Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I switched to Filehelpers which suports this as standard didnt see any advantages over Filehelpers csvhelper provides